# Graphviz dot not work on OS X Yosemite

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a dot file that I want to convert to a `ps` or `png`. 
Graphviz is installed with `brew` on OS X Yosemite. 
However, `dot` fails to convert with the following output:

```
Borkdude@macbookair-michiel /tmp $ dot -Tps foo.dot -o foo.ps
Format: "ps" not recognized. Use one of:
```

Where to look next?

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

As this issue is most likely caused by a botched update or install, the most simple solution is to completely uninstall and then re-install Graphviz.

### The Long Version

#### Check supported formats

The first thing to do is [see what formats dot supports](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html). Following the instructions from the manual, this is achieved by running:

```
dot -T?
```

This should output something along the lines of

```
Format: "?" not recognized. Use one of: bmp canon cgimage cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot 
eps exr fig gif gv icns ico imap imap_np ismap jp2 jpe jpeg jpg pct pdf pic pict 
plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 psd sgi svg svgz tga tif tiff tk vml vmlz xdot 
xdot1.2 xdot1.4
```

Based on the output you're getting, `ps` will not be in that list.

### Check config file

There is [a bug report of a similar issue](http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=1261) which suggest validating that a `config` file exists (mine was `/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.38.0/lib/graphviz/config6`).

If it does exist, grep for `ps` to see if it is in fact mentioned in the config. If it is not, reinstall is required.

If it does *not* exist, run `dot -c` to create one.

#### Visit the forum

If this does not resolve the issue, the next step would be to go on the [Graphviz Forum](http://www.graphviz.org/Forum) and ask for helpt there.

Comment: This solution is still valid as of today for Yosemite 10.10.5 and graphviz 2.40.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using the following steps

1. Uninstall `graphviz` using `brew remove graphviz`
2. Install [macports](http://www.macports.org/)
3. `sudo port -v selfupdate
   sudo port install graphviz-gui`